# How does my input not equal the answer?

Tags: python, string, int

Switching from Unity JS to Python for a bit, and some of the finer points elude me as to why this does not work.
My best guess is that the variable `guess` is actually a string, so string 5 is not the same as integer 5?
Is this what is happening and either way how does one go about fixing this.

```
import random
import operator

ops = {
    '+':operator.add,
    '-':operator.sub
}
def generateQuestion():
    x = random.randint(1, 10)
    y = random.randint(1, 10)
    op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
    a = ops.get(op)(x,y)
    print("What is {} {} {}?\n".format(x, op, y))
    return a

def askQuestion(a):
    guess = input("")
    if guess == a:
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Wrong, the answer is",a)

askQuestion(generateQuestion())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are using python3.

The only problem with your code is that the value you get from `input()` is a string and not a integer. So you need to convert that.

```
string_input = input('Question?')
try:
    integer_input = int(string_input)
except ValueError:
    print('Please enter a valid number')
```

Now you have the input as a integer and you can compare it to `a`

Edited Code:

```
import random
import operator

ops = {
    '+':operator.add,
    '-':operator.sub
}
def generateQuestion():
    x = random.randint(1, 10)
    y = random.randint(1, 10)
    op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
    a = ops.get(op)(x,y)
    print("What is {} {} {}?\n".format(x, op, y))
    return a

def askQuestion(a):
    # you get the user input, it will be a string. eg: "5"
    guess = input("")
    # now you need to get the integer
    # the user can input everything but we cant convert everything to an integer so we use a try/except
    try:
        integer_input = int(guess)
    except ValueError:
        # if the user input was "this is a text" it would not be a valid number so the exception part is executed
        print('Please enter a valid number')
        # if the code in a function comes to a return it will end the function
        return
    if integer_input == a:
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Wrong, the answer is",a)

askQuestion(generateQuestion())
```

Comment: Sorry for being a rookie, but I'm not sure how to implement your suggestion properly

Comment: @MattNewton i can understand that. it isnt too long ago when i could not write any proper python code 

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are absolutely right that `"5"` is distinct from `5`. You can convert `5` into a string by using `str(5)`. An alternative would be to convert `"5"` into an integer by `int("5")` but that option can fail, so better handle the exception.

So, the change to your program could be e.g. the following:

```
if guess == str(a):
```

instead of:

```
if guess == a:
```

Another option would be to convert guess into an integer, as explained in the other answer.

EDIT: This only applies to Python versions 2.x:

However, you're using `input()`, not `raw_input()`. `input()` returns an integer if you type an integer (and fails if you type text that isn't a valid Python expression). I tested your program and it asked `What is 4 - 2?`; I typed `2` and it sait `Correct!` so I don't see what is your problem.

Have you noticed that if your program asks `What is 9 - 4?` you can type `9  - 4` and it says `Correct!`? That's due to you using `input()`, not `raw_input()`. Similarly, if you type e.g. `c`, your program fails with `NameError`

I would however use `raw_input()` and then compare the answer to `str(correct_answer)`

Comment: i am pretty sure that OP is using python3 where there is no raw_input()

Comment: No idea how you yield a correct result :) I tried it again to make sure I wasn't suffering from brain derp and still get wrong with every combination.   
And yes raw_input() does not work for me as i use 3.4.

So while I value your answer, I'm still stuck :)