# Why is the entire loop code is being ignored?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The block of loop code is ignored and only the initial value is being used. It works well till I input *fin* and then simply the value 0 (as I have initialised it like that) is output as shown in the code.

I'm trying to make a very basic voting system with numbers as input.

```
z = 0
a = 0
b = 0
while z != 'fin':
    n = input()
    if n == 1:
        a = int(a) + 1
    elif n == 2:
        b = int(b) + 1
    else:
        pass
    z = n
c = 'kushagra'
d = 'kunaal'
print(f"{c} got {a} votes.\n{d} got {b} votes")
```

Comment: Input returns a string, which is never a number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does my input not equal the answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29205967/how-does-my-input-not-equal-the-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Like Mad Physicist said, n is a string not a number. 
I changed the code to this :

```
z = 0
a = 0
b = 0

while z != 'fin':
    n = input()

    if n == '1':
        a += 1
    elif n == '2':
        b += 1
    else:
        pass

    z = n

c = 'kushagra'
d = 'kunaal'

print(f"{c} got {a} votes.\n{d} got {b} votes")
```

And it seems to work.