# Python, condition with a random number

Tags: python, logic

what's wrong with this code? since the guess is 4, and the dice was 4 too, it's supposed to print "Impressive"...... why is it firing the else clouse?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't matter much here since the code is short and the problem obvious, but in future, can you put code as text, not as a screenshot? Type ``` (3 backticks) and then the code, and then another ``` to end the code

Comment: You need to cast your input to an integer, e.g. `if dice == int(guess):`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does my input not equal the answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29205967/how-does-my-input-not-equal-the-answer)

Answer (score 2):

the return type of `input()` is `str` and randint returns `int`

so basically ur trying to do 4 == '4', which will return False

Comment: So, tell him how to fix it.  `guess = int(input(...))`.